# Track Community Session Login Timestamp via Global Header or URL

Tags: community, custom-object, session, login, header-bar

Lets say User has 3 communities [`Community A` (A.com), `Community B` (B.com), `Community C` (C.com)] with same username. Same Licence. You have given access to community via `profile for Community A` and with `permission sets for Community B and Community C`.

How do you track whether the user logged into A or B or C communities via A.com or B.com Or C.com? Also how to track if the user is using Global Header to switch between different communities?

I am somewhat new to SalesForce, please let me know if this is a good approach..

Create a custom object with following fields: UserID, Community Name, Login Time, Type(URL/Global Header). Can this information can be filled by using the user session?

Is this the best approach or is there anything simpler or better?

**Update:** I need this information for `Reporting` Purposes, to let community managers know if a user has logged into that community or not..

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways you can track the engagements for each community

1.Install the community manager App from appexchange

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5XHsEAN

This will get you last logins for each community .

[image]

2.Take login history of the user .There is a field called login URL and that will show your users login to various communities .

Comment: Taking Option 2: I need to make a report on the number of users who logged into per community and I cannot find Login URL. Am I missing something?

Comment: The option 1 has excellent dashboards on adoption .Please try it before ignoring it completely